# How can I stop this repetitive if else and conditions in this code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that recieves an initial width, height, their ratio and the user device.
Now user can define the width and height of the image in % or in px or just 'auto' string. So, I had to use all the cases which can occure. But now the code is huge and seems complex. I want to reduce this if-else hell and make the code more dynamic and optimised. Can someone give me any idea how to do it.

```js
const getSize = (width, height, ratio, device) => {
    const myWidth =
        device === 'Mobile'
            ? item.media?.mobile?.style?.width
            : device === 'Tablet'
            ? item.media?.tablet?.style?.width
            : item.style?.width;
    const myHeight =
        device === 'Mobile'
            ? item.media?.mobile?.style?.height
            : device === 'Tablet'
            ? item.media?.tablet?.style?.height
            : item.style?.height;

    const widthCondition = !myWidth || myWidth === 'auto';
    const heightCondition = !myHeight || myHeight === 'auto';

    if (widthCondition) {
        setNewWidth(width);
        const pixelHeight = findHeightOrWidth(width, ratio);
        setNewHeight(pixelHeight);
        return;
    }

    if (myWidth.includes('%')) {
        const percentage = parseInt(myWidth, 10);
        const calculatedWidth = getPercentValue(width, percentage);
        setNewWidth(calculatedWidth);

        if (heightCondition) {
            const calculatedHeight = getPercentValue(height, percentage);
            setNewHeight(calculatedHeight);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (myWidth.includes('px')) {
        setNewWidth(parseInt(myWidth, 10));
        if (heightCondition) {
            const pixelWidth = parseInt(myWidth, 10);
            const pixelHeight = findHeightOrWidth(pixelWidth, ratio);
            setNewHeight(pixelHeight);
        } else {
            setNewHeight(parseInt(myHeight, 10));
        }
        return;
    }

    if (myHeight?.includes('%')) {
        const percentage = parseInt(myHeight, 10);
        const calculatedHeight = getPercentValue(height, percentage);
        setNewHeight(calculatedHeight);
        if (widthCondition) {
            const calculatedWidth = getPercentValue(height, percentage);
            setNewWidth(calculatedWidth);
        }
        return;
    }

    if (myHeight?.includes('px')) {
        setNewHeight(parseInt(myHeight, 10));
        if (widthCondition) {
            const pixelHeight = parseInt(myHeight, 10);
            const pixelWidth = findHeightOrWidth(pixelHeight, ratio);
            setNewWidth(pixelWidth);
        } else {
            setNewWidth(parseInt(myWidth, 10));
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please list the total device types? and also can you explain the working of this line?
`const widthCondition = !myWidth || myWidth === 'auto';`

Comment: const device =
            props.target.naturalWidth < 420
                ? 'Mobile'
                : props.target.naturalWidth < 768
                ? 'Tablet'
                : 'Desktop';

Comment: const widthCondition = !myWidth || myWidth === 'auto'; this is just a condition if my width case as undefined or as string 'auto'

Comment: Ok, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
let myWidth = item.style?.width;
if (device === 'Mobile') myWidth = item.media?.mobile?.style?.width;
else if (device === 'Tablet') myWidth = item.media?.tablet?.style?.width;

let myHeight = item.style?.height;
if (device === 'Mobile') myHeight = item.media?.mobile?.style?.height;
if (device === 'Tablet') myHeight = item.media?.tablet?.style?.height;

const widthCondition = !myWidth || myWidth === 'auto';
const heightCondition = !myHeight || myHeight === 'auto';
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach will be to like this

```
const getSize = (width, height, ratio, device) => {
  deviceWidths = {
    Mobile = item.media?.mobile?.style?.width,
    Tablet = item.media?.tablet?.style?.width,
    Desktop = item.media??.style?.width
  }

  deviceHeights = {
    Mobile = item.media?.mobile?.style?.height,
    Tablet = item.media?.tablet?.style?.height,
    Web = item.media??.style?.height
  }

  const myWidth = deviceWidths[device];
  const myHeight = deviceHeights[device];

  const widthCondition = myWidth || myWidth === 'auto';
  const heightCondition = !myHeight || myHeight === 'auto';

  if (widthCondition) {
    setNewWidth(width);
    const pixelHeight = findHeightOrWidth(width, ratio);
    setNewHeight(pixelHeight);
    return;
  }

  if (myWidth.includes('%')) {
    setNewDimensionInPercentage('width', heightCondition, myWidth, height, width);
  }
  if (myWidth.includes('px')) {
    setDimentionInPixels('width', heightCondition, myWidth, ratio)
  }

  if (myHeight.includes('%')) {
    setNewDimensionInPercentage('height', widthCondition, myHeight, height, width);
  }
  if (myHeight.includes('px')) {
    setDimentionInPixels('height', widthCondition, myHeight, ratio)
  }
}


setNewDimensionInPercentage(dimentionType, dimensionCondition, dimention, height, width){
    const isWidth = dimentionType === 'width';
    const percentage = parseInt(dimention, 10);
    const calculatedWidthOrHeight = getPercentValue(isWidth ? width :height, percentage);
    isWidth ? setNewWidth(calculatedWidthOrHeight) : setNewHeight(calculatedWidthOrHeight);
    if (dimensionCondition) {
        const calculatedHeightOrWidth = getPercentValue(isWidth ? height : width, percentage);
        isWidth ? setNewHeight(calculatedHeightOrWidth) : setNewWidth(calculatedHeightOrWidth);
    }
    return;
}

setDimentionInPixels(dimentionType, dimensionCondition, dimention, ratio)){
    const isWidth = dimentionType === 'width';
    isWidth ? setNewWidth(parseInt(dimention, 10)) : setNewHeight(parseInt(dimention, 10));
    if (dimensionCondition) {
        if(isWidth){
          const pixelWidth = parseInt(dimention, 10);
          const pixelHeight = findHeightOrWidth(pixelWidth, ratio);
        } else {
          const pixelHeight = parseInt(dimention, 10);
          const pixelWidth = findHeightOrWidth(pixelHeight, ratio);
        }
        isWidth ? setNewHeight(pixelHeight) : setNewWidth(pixelWidth);
    } else {
        isWidth ? setNewHeight(parseInt(dimention, 10)) : setNewWidth(parseInt(dimention, 10));
    }
    return;
}
```

This is just the basic idea and approach. You can simplify it more according to your needs.

**There can be some type, sorry in advance for that. Because i haven't test it.**